# jquery parallax effect starting from an existing 50% background-position-y

Tags: jquery, parallax

I've been working on some parallaxing using a few different parallax plugins as well as some home built parallax code.  My problems is that all the parallaxing code I've looked at adjusts the background-position-y by pixels.  I'm trying to start off with my background image set to cover and an initial background-position as center center or "50% 50%".  When the parallax code kicks in, I believe it's assuming it's starting from a background-position-y of 0px.

I would like to start my parallax from the current position of the background-image.  This is difficult when that position is 50%.  Any ideas how I might be able to do this?  Here's some example code.  Hope it makes sense.

using Ian Lunn's plugin:
http://www.ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/

```
    section {
        position: relative;
        width: 1900px;
        height: 834px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: 50% 50% no-repeat fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        background-image: url("img/image_1.jpg");
     }
```

jquery:

```
$('section').parallax("50%", .6);
```

The plugin makes some calculations based on the container height and scroll position and uses the speed to calculate a new y position, only it doesn't take into account the existing y position (first of all), but that could easily be added in there.  I just don't know how to do it if there is no exact Y position.  The result is that there's a jump when you start scrolling as the original background-position-y of 50% is overridden with, say -10px.

make sense?  Unfortunately, I don't have a working example to show.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

I amended calculation of var which controls background position by adding the difference (instead of `top:0 top:50%`). First you need to get the [image height](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/finding-the-width-of-a-background-image):

```
var path = $('#id').css('background-image').replace('url', '').replace('(', '').replace(')', ''); 

var tempImg = '<img id='tempImg' src='+path+' />';

$('html').append(tempImg);
$('#tempImg').hide(); //hide image
var height = $('#tempImg').height(); //get height
$('#tempImg').remove(); //remove from DOM
```

Then get the container height and the position of 50% in px:

```
var contheight = $('#id').height();
var start = (-(height - contheight) / 2);
```

Then add this to the stating position. Mine was:

```
var yPos = start + ( $(window).scrollTop()- $('#id').offset().top) * (1-ratio);
```

Or use some other [more flexible parallax script](http://www.minimit.com/articles/lets-animate/parallax-backgrounds-with-centered-content).

Comment: While this link may answer the part of the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Links can become invalid if the linked page changes.